# Defining macro function from makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile, macros

Suppose I have following entry in my makefile:

```
ifeq ($(MY_DEBUG),yes) 
EXTRACXXFLAGS += -DMY_DEBUG=2
endif
```

I am invoking it with `make foo MY_DEBUG=yes` and now I basically have

```
#define MY_DEBUG 2
```

for all project files available.

**Question:** Can I define the macro *function* all over the project this way, without including some kind of header file with `-include` or other ways?

What I need is something like this in my makefile:

```
/* not working code */
ifeq ($(MY_DEBUG),yes) 
EXTRACXXFLAGS += -Ddbg_print(...)=printf(##__VA_ARGS__)
endif
```

Normally I would define this macro function in some header, included all over the project, but this particular project is way too big and doesn't have such a header.

---

#### Way to go if one has a header file included all over the place:

`Makefile`

```
# this is in makefile
ifeq ($(MY_DEBUG),yes) 
EXTRACXXFLAGS += -DMY_DEBUG
endif
```

`globally_included_header.h`

```
// header, included all over the project
#ifdef MY_DEBUG
#    define dbg_print(...) printf(##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#    define dbg_print(...)
#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert a header from the command line to all sources by adding this to the CXX flags:

```
-include "path/to/header.h"
```

**EDIT:**

In your particular case you could also pass this to the `CXX` flags to make a macro function:

```
-D'dbg_print(...)=printf(__VA_ARGS__)'
```

on windows it worked for me with `"` and not with `'`

Comment: What I want to know - is there a way NOT to include this kind of header?

Comment: @arbulgazar: You do not need to add this header to any file manually. The compiler flag `-include` does that automatically for you. It acts as if all your source files started with `#include "globally_included_header.h"`. Putting your `dbg_print` definition in a file avoids the command shell quoting hell.

Comment: `-D'dbg_print(...)=printf(__VA_ARGS__)'` not working for me with all kinds of ```, `"`, `'`. :(

Comment: I'll accept this answer as I am actually using it, but I don't like this `-include` solution for some reason... Quotes still not working..

Comment: @arbulgazar Well I read about this [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html) (search for function) and tested it only on Windows with ```Mingw-w64``` (with double quotes) - there must be a way to do it in unix...

Answer (score 1):

You can include such a header to all source files with `gcc -include` or `cl -FI` (Windows Visual Studio).

Just put your debug function in a file, guarded by an `#ifdef` and specify the debug flag and the file in your make command.

To summarize:

In the Makefile

```
ifeq ($(MY_DEBUG),yes) 
EXTRACXXFLAGS += -DMY_DEBUG
endif
...
    $(CC) $(EXTRACXXFLAGS) -include globally_included_header.h ...
```

In the globally_included_header.h

```
// header, included all over the project
#ifdef MY_DEBUG
#    define dbg_print(...) printf(##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#    define dbg_print(...)
#endif
```